# Does Swift execute the methods of a class as part of initializing it?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, singleton, runtime

I have [a singleton (code here)](https://gist.github.com/MosheBerman/1fbc4d220cd195ef31be) inheriting from `NSObject` that calls some method whenever I access the shared instance. It looks like this is happening before some other state is initialized and it seems to be crashing.

The class has generated initializers, so I wonder if this is a Swift bug. The [method](https://gist.github.com/MosheBerman/1fbc4d220cd195ef31be#file-submissionmanager-swift-L185-L190) shouldn't be called at all.

Is there some implementation detail in Swift or Cocoa that a class's methods are executed upon or as part of initialization?

Comment: I've never encountered that with pure Swift or Swift classes inheriting from NSObject, can you post some code?

Comment: @thefredelement The code is here: https://gist.github.com/MosheBerman/1fbc4d220cd195ef31be

Comment: Are you sure that method is the error? It looks like your static member will always give you a new instance of a Submission Manager - are you running into some thread/state issue somewhere?

Comment: It's actually only going to give one instance. See this: https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

Comment: Are you keeping a reference to it so it's not deallocated?

Comment: Nope,  but why would that matter?

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question. What is "some method" and "some other state"? What is the message you're getting from the crash? Is it possible the method is being called from somewhere else?

Comment: @CleverError The method is never called from inside the class, so no. The method in question is `testServerConnection()` and the state is the `serverURLComponents`.

Answer (score 0):

Showed to a Swift engineer, seems like it's a bug. Filed a Radar.